# class accepting any attribute

Tags: python

Is it possible to define a python class which not return an AttributeError exception if an attribute is called but not existing in the class instance? Like

```
class A():
    pass

a = A()
a.tutu <==not raising AttributeError
```

thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of raising the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `__getattr__` method on your class.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Here's a simple example that gives all missing attributes the value "Default":

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         return "Default"
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.someJunk
'Default'
```

Comment: users of this should be aware that this will cause all `hasattr` calls to return `True`, and also will never actually add the attributes to the object's `__dict__` on calls.